# Graphite not accepting values in the future

Tags: graphite

I'm investigating Graphite as a possible TSDB database.

The problem I have is that Graphite is not writing values that are in the future? Am I missing something?

Simple test with nc

`echo "psoll 20 1570560798" | nc localhost 2003 -D`

The above given unix timestamp has to be in the future.

Comment: Is graphite definitely not writing the values or are you just not able to retrieve/query them? Whisper will return you nothing if a datapoint is from the future: https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper/blob/60c8b9bab5dff6bdafca6880aafca5fcadc0aa77/whisper.py#L919

To test if it's being written, try sending a datapoint a few minutes into the future, then wait for that time to pass and try retrieve the data.

Comment: What a pity. I also planned to use Graphite for forecast time series and the standard use case is to write **and** retrieve future data points.

So I guess, that Graphite won't fit my needs.

Comment: You could try changing that behaviour yourself :) try returning the data instead of `None`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: Graphite is open source, you can modify the source code before installing it. Perhaps by changing what is being returned when you request data from the future, you might get your data.

Did you try sending a datapoint with a future timestamp of around 2-3 minutes, and then wait for that time to pass to then request it - was the data there? If so, then there's no problem writing the future datapoints, just when you're requesting them.

Comment: You're supposed to use the `timeShift` function on your metric. Here is a discussion that explains the reasoning behind this https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/205821.